# Mobile-friendly test: Couldn't load 36 page resources?

Tags: magento-1.9, seo

Google's mobile-friendly test on my new site says it is mobile friendly, but there were "Page load issues." It returned:

https://search.google.com/search-console/mobile-friendly?id=OWamZS02QnHWnNeP6njbIQ&view=fetch-info

Page partially loaded
Not all page resources could be loaded. This can affect how Google sees and understands your page. Fix availability problems for any resources that can affect how Google understands your page.

Then it lists 36 resources that apparently didn't load, things like:
http://www.googlecommerce.com/trustedstores/api/js - Script - Other error
http://www.example.com/js/lightboxes/fancybox/blank.gif - Image -Other error
http://www.example.com/js/lightboxes/fancybox/fancybox.png - Image - Other error
http://www.example.com/skin/frontend/my_theme/default/fonts/cutive-regular-webfont.ttf  - Font - Other error

Answer (score 0):

When the Google mobile friendly test says that a resource could not be loaded, it usually means that it is blocked by robots.txt. Check your robots.txt file and ensure that you don't disallow Googlebot from crawling these resources.

You can further diagnose the issue using the "Fetch as Google" feature in Google Search Console. Plug one of the resource URLs into this tool and Google would give more detailed information about why it would not be able to fetch it.